Terraform fails to create Azure storage container
I'm attempting to use Terraform to create a number of resources in Azure. It appears to be working until I get to the creation of a backup storage container.
Here's my Terraform code:
Resource Group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource-group" {
  name     = "${var.resource_prefix}-${var.environment}-rg-${var.project_name_web}"
  location = var.location

  tags = {
    environment = var.environment
  }
}

Storage Account
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage-account" {
  name                     = "${var.resource_prefix}${var.environment}storage${var.project_name_web}"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.resource-group.name
  location                 = var.location
  account_tier             = var.storage_account_tier
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  account_kind             = var.storage_account_kind
  access_tier              = var.storage_access_tier

  tags = {
    environment = var.environment
  }
}

Storage Container
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "storage-account-container-media" {
  name                  = var.storage_container_media_name
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.storage-account.name
  container_access_type = var.storage_container_media_access_type
}

Vault
resource "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" "vault" {
  name                = "${var.resource_prefix}-${var.environment}-vault-${var.project_name_web}"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource-group.name
  sku                 = "Standard"

  tags = {
    environment = var.environment
  }
}

Vault Container
resource "azurerm_backup_container_storage_account" "vault-container" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource-group.name
  recovery_vault_name = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.vault.name
  storage_account_id  = azurerm_storage_account.storage-account.id
}

It looks to be failing on the last of these with the following error:
Error: Recovery Service Protection Container operation status failed with status "Failed" (Vault "group-dev-vault-web" Resource Group "group-dev-rg-web" Operation ID "09239f11-eab5-407d-afeb-796d64b6a46f"): Item not found
with azurerm_backup_container_storage_account.vault-container
on infra-staging-web.tf line 97, in resource "azurerm_backup_container_storage_account" "vault-container":
resource "azurerm_backup_container_storage_account" "vault-container" {

It seems to indicate that something is missing but I've checked that the resource group, vault, and storage accounts are present in Azure. I've also checked the identifiers used in this block and, as far as I can tell, they look to be correct.
What am I doing wrong?

Did you try including depends_on in your azurerm_backup_container_storage_account configuration @ONeji refer:https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/configuration-language/dependencies


Create Azure storage container using terraform

As per the error description which mentioned as Item not found Azure Recovery Services Vault is unable to find the storage account container.
This may be delay to availablity of the resource before you actually use. Here in this case azurerm_backup_container_storage_account resource tries to reference the storage account before it is fully registered in Azure Recovery Services.
You can use depends_on where the terraform make sure the use of the target resouce occurs only after the resource completely created and ready to use.
Configuration:
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "storage-account-container-media" {
  name                  = var.storage_container_media_name
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.storage-account.name
  container_access_type = var.storage_container_media_access_type
}

resource "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" "vault" {
  name                = "${var.resource_prefix}-${var.environment}-vault-${var.project_name_web}"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource-group.name
  sku                 = "Standard"
}


resource "azurerm_backup_container_storage_account" "vault-container" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource-group.name
  recovery_vault_name = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.vault.name
  storage_account_id  = azurerm_storage_account.storage-account.id
  
  depends_on = [azurerm_storage_account.storage-account]
}

Deployement:


Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-recovery-services-vault-overview

Sadly didn't solve the issue, I've even gone so far as to destroy resources and recreate them. Tried multiple runs (theory being that the second run it wouldn't fail because the storage is there).

if the problem future exists you can use time_sleep to delay the operation so that it can match the delay @ONegi
